# Why does $http check to see if response data is string

Tags: angularjs

The default transformation of data in angular's $http service is to check if it is a string, and if not return whatever it is. This makes unit testing easier because you can mock return POJOs instead of json strings.

Is there any non testing case for this behaviour?

```
transformResponse: [function(data) {
  if (isString(data)) {
    // strip json vulnerability protection prefix
    data = data.replace(PROTECTION_PREFIX, '');
    if (JSON_START.test(data) && JSON_END.test(data))
      data = fromJson(data);
  }
  return data;
}]
```

Comment: Isn't "POJO" a Java-specific thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of the `data` argument depends on the **[`responseType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#response)** of the XHR.

In most cases (and by default) it is a string, but (as more and more browsers support the XHR Level 2 spec (<sub>**cough** IE10 and above **cough**</sub>)) it can also be an ArrayBuffer, Blob, Document or JavaScript object.